# bootstrap.min.css file contains content: '\e257', but after running it changed to '?'

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css files are written correctly,
and all content is displayed properly in the files, 
for example

```
.glyphicon- Menu-left: before {content: "\e257"}
```

But when I run my website, instead of icons, there are question marks, 
and when I open the file bootstrap.min.css in the Developer Tools window, I see the content is defined as a question mark.

[image]

How did this happen? When and why CSS file is changed from '\e257' to '?' and how can I fix it?

EDIT:

I found the point that makes it happen, but still don't know why.

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
When bootstrap included init.

`bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                       "~/Content/Font/fonts.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery-ui-1.11.4.css"));
        }`

Changing the bootstrap to contain question marks.

But once I bring the bootstrap alone. ** After ** the icons displayed correctly:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: Are you compiling your CSS perhaps?

Comment: Not sure if it's just a mistake while copy-pasting or something, but there seems to be a space between the backslash and `e257`. Remove it and try again.

Comment: @Chris: No, it's a mistake while copying. (I downloaded the file from bootstrap, there, it's of course, written correctly

Comment: @DavidG what do you mean?

Comment: @BIBI, He's probably asking if you are using something like [tag:LESS] or [tag:SASS].

Comment: @BIBI make sure your file is UTF-8 encoding